# which image of AWS to choose for PHP?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-aws

I want to set up a linux server that will run moodle (an application in PHP) on AWS.

I think the best two images to choose from are:

Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)

Amazon Linux 2 comes with five years support. It provides Linux kernel 4.14 tuned for optimal performance on Amazon EC2, systemd 219, GCC 7.3, Glibc 2.26, Binutils 2.29.1, and the latest software packages through extras.

Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)

The Amazon Linux AMI is an EBS-backed, AWS-supported image. The default image includes AWS command line tools, Python, Ruby, Perl, and Java. The repositories include Docker, PHP, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and other packages.

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Turns out Linux 2 AMI had all the packages I needed from its standard repositories to run moodle. I was afraid this wasn't the case because of difference in the description between Linux AMI and Linux 2 AMI.